# Is the vector in the span?

Tags: linear-algebra, maple

I have to show that $a_4$ is in the span of the other 3 vectors $a_1,a_2,a_3$

\begin{bmatrix}
       2 &1 & 3\\
       3 & -1 & 4 \\
       1 & 2 & -1 \\
4 & 4 & 3 \\
0 & 3 & 5 \\
          & 
     \end{bmatrix}
My Maple code:
with (LinearAlgebra);

A := <<2, 1, 3>,<3, -1, 4>,<1, 2, -1>,<4, 4, 3>,<0, 3, 5>>;
Then i use ReducedRowEchelon to get the linear combination which is 
M=:{{1,0,0},{0,1,0},{0,0,1},{0,0,0}, {0,0,0} }.

How do i prove that $a_4$ which is {-3,-6,5,2,7} is in the span of the other 3 vectors?

Comment: Oh, dear! Please use LaTeX here to write mathematics, otherwise things like your question are hard to read. Refer to the FAQ section for direction

Comment: To do this, in general, I recommend checking out [this previous answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/56206/17349).

Comment: So that meaning 
a*a1+b*a2+c*a3=a4
a(2,3,1,4,0)+b(1,-1,2,4,3)+c(3,4,-1,3,5)=a4

Comment: We already have a problem here, which may be a typo (a serious one) or simply a mistake in the question: all your vector are 3-dimensional...except $\,a_4\,$, which is 5-dimensiona (in spite of having written it with curly parentheses intead of <>, as the other ones). This can't be as $\,a_4\,$ doesn't even live in the same universe as the other vectors.

Comment: Well I just copy pasted from Maple for that Vector.
Gonna read up on Latex and try to do it in that format ASAP

Comment: Hmmm...so the vectors are that matrix's columns? I would have never guessed that.

Comment: Yeah sry for misleading :)

Answer (score 2):

I am making an example here for you in Maple, so you can do yours as well. I think it inspires you well. Assume you have 3 vector as: $$u=\langle 2,1,-3,1 \rangle, v=\langle -1,3,5,0 \rangle,w=\langle 2,-1,1,-3 \rangle$$ and want to find scalars in which we can write the vector $$b=\langle -16,17,37,3 \rangle$$ as their combinations. You can do by:

> [>with(linalg):
>
> [> u:=matrix(4,1,[2,1,-3,1]):
>
> [> v:=matrix(4,1,[-1,3,5,0]):
>
> [> w:=matrix(4,1,[2,-1,1,-3]):
>
> [> b:=matrix(4,1,[-16,17,37,3]):
>
> [> A:=augment(u,v,w):
>
> [> linsolve(A,b);

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Yes. Thanks for noting me that.

Comment: Nice...so you know Gap, and Maple, and ... ???? !!!

Comment: @amWhy: Again, it is Maple :-)