# How this vector spans $\mathbb R^3$?

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, span

I am having trouble to understand why this given vector spans $ \mathbb R^3$.

$V=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}-4\\-6\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}2\\-1\\-4\end{bmatrix}\right\}$

I understand that a non-zero determinant shows that the given set spans the space. However, this is not the square matrix. Therefore, I can not use determinant. I searched online and found this thread.

[How to tell if a set of vectors spans a space?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56201/how-to-tell-if-a-set-of-vectors-spans-a-space)

According to this thread, we can use row reductions to calculate the rank of the given matrix. If it is equal to space, we can say that it spans this. I tried to row reduce this and end up with

$\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}$

This shows that the rank is $2$. Therefore, please explain how to arrive at the solution and why it spans $\mathbb R^3$. I know there are lots of questions about spanning sets. I am still kinda confused about calculating spans. I use the following procedure:

$1)$ if the matrix is square, non-zero determinant shows span. If not, rank tells span.

Please guide me is this correct way? or should I use any other procedure?
Thanks. please explain in detail.

Comment: your set Vector doesn't span $\Bbb R^3$

Comment: Following @janmarqz's comment, you need at least 3 vectors to span $\mathbb R^3$, but that condition is certainly not sufficient.

Comment: A spanning set of a vector space should have cardinality at least the dimension of the vector space. Moreover, if the given set spans $\Bbb{R}^{3}$, then we can solve two equations with three unknowns.

Comment: It will, however, span a **subspace** of $\Bbb R^3$, namely the subspace $span\left\{ \left[\begin{smallmatrix} -4\\-6\\0\end{smallmatrix} \right], \left[\begin{smallmatrix} 2\\-1\\-4 \end{smallmatrix}\right] \right\}$

Comment: Why are people downvoting this post? OP has clearly shown his/her (extensive) research, even to the point where OP has actually finished the problem and shown that we do not have spanning.

Answer (score 3):

The set $\{(−4, −6, 0), (2, −1, −4)\}$ does not span $\mathbb R^3$. The set contains only two vectors, so its span is at most $2$-dimensional. In fact, since $(−4, −6, 0)$ and $(2, −1, −4)$ are linearly independent, the span is exactly $2$-dimensional.